# Abelian $p$-group and proof of the existence of cyclic subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, p-groups

Consider the theorem

> Let $G$ be a finite Abelian group with order $|G|=p^n$ and $a$ an element of maximal order in $G$, then there is a subgroup $H$ of $G$ such that $G\cong |a|\times H$.

I'm interested only in the begin of the proof (I've seen some online and all go a similar way through). Consider $H$ the maximal subgroup of $G$ with $H\cap \langle a\rangle =\{e\}$.

No one says in his proof why this subgroup exist. I must miss something very elementary. I undestand the following: Lets take $b\in G-\langle a\rangle$, then $\langle a\rangle\cap \langle b\rangle=\{e\}$. Now the problem arises from the maximality. Let's take $c\in G-\langle a\rangle\langle b\rangle$ (we consider that $b$ and $c$ exist otherwise we are already done).

> What can I say about $\langle b\rangle\langle c\rangle$? Could we build $H$ iteratively $H=\langle b\rangle\langle c\rangle\cdots$?

Comment: If $H$ is a subgroup satisfying the condition that $\langle a \rangle \cap H = \{e\}$, then any subgroup of $H$ also satisfies this condition. The _minimal_ subgroup satisfying this condition is $\{e\}$. In fact, since this is _one_ subgroup satisfying the condition, and since the group is finite (so there is no infinitely ascending chain of subgroups), we know that "maximal subgroup $H$ such that $H \cap \langle a \rangle = \{e\}$" is well defined and must exist.

Comment: Your question about $\langle b \rangle$ and $\langle c \rangle$ is not really clear (to me at least). Are you saying that what you have constructed seems to contradict maximality or the possibility of there being such a maximal subgroup?

Comment: @M.Vinay Your first point. You could have $H$ and $H'$ satisfying the condition but neither $H\le H'$ or $H'\le H$. I mean lattice of subgroups.

Comment: Oh, so you're worried about uniqueness of the maximal subgroup. But that's not required. You can have two different subgroups maximally satisfying the property. Unless you want to additionally prove that there's a unique one.

Comment: @M.Vinay Your second point. with $b$ and $c$, I'm trying to build $H$. My conjecture is that with iterative finding of excluded elements we build $H$ by subgroup multiplication of the spanns.

Comment: @M.Vinay: Now I got the first point. Thank you. I'm still interested on the second, the construction.

Comment: Okay, so you take an element $b$ that is not generated by $a$. But how do you know $a$ is not generated by $b$ (for if it is, then $\langle b \rangle \cap \langle a \rangle \ne \{e\}$ )? (There's an answer, but I don't know whether you've thought about it or not). And then for $c$, I think you want $c \in G - \langle a, b \rangle$.

Answer (score 1):

$G$ is finite, and you know $H=\{e\}$ satisfies your condition, so you can just take $H$ of maximum order that satisfies this condition. You don't actually have to construct it.